# Prove that $\frac{x}{y} \leq \ln(y) - \ln(y - x)$

Tags: logarithms

I am supposed to prove that $\frac{x}{y} \leq \ln(y) - \ln(y-x)$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 \leq x < y$.

So I've been thinking about going with a case distinction. First is the obvious case for $x=0$. Then I thought about doing more case distinctions where I differ whether $|y - x|$ is smaller, equals or larger to 1. But already in th easiest case for $|y-x| = 1$ I pretty much get stuck. I have no idea how I'm supposed to get the logarithm into the inequality.

So I'd be more than glad about a tiny hint here.

Comment: $y - x = y\bigl(1 - \frac{x}{y}\bigr)$

Comment: $e^t\ge 1+t$ for all $t\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know $e^t \geq t + 1 $ for all $t$. In particular, $e^{-t} \leq \frac{1}{1+t}$.

Put $t = - \frac{x}{y}$. Then,

$$ e^{\frac{x}{y}} \leq \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{y}} \implies \frac{x}{y} \leq \ln \left( \frac{y}{y-x} \right)$$

as we wanted to show.

Comment: goddamn can math be easy! I got stuck at the part where I have $e^\frac{x}{y}$ and $\frac{x}{y} - 1$ and didn't think about inverting the inequality about $e$! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Set $x=ty,\quad 0\le t<1$. You have to proove 
$$t\le \ln y-\ln(y-x)=-\ln(1-t).$$
Use the Taylor's series expansion of $\ln(1-t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $t\in [y-x,y]\to \ln t.$ Because of the mean value theorem for derivatives there exists $c\in (y-x,y)$ such that

$$\ln y-\ln(y-x)=\frac{d\ln}{dx}|_c (y-(y-x))=\frac{x}{c}.$$ Now, $x/c>x/y$ since $c<y.$